# Flow of Compiler

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to Database programming language. When I'm going through key words like

```
RAISE VALUE ERROR
```

What I understood is that the compiler directly goes to the exceptions block of that transaction .

My question is what if there is a block following it having the `PRAGMA 'Autonomous_TRANSACTION'` How the block executes when the compiler directly goes to the exception block.

Can you please explain how the flow works when key words like `RAISE VALUE ERROR`, `AUTONOUMOUS_TRANSACTION` are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising an exception is exactly the same as executing a GOTO statement: any code between the RAISE and the EXCEPTION block is ignored.

This demo uses DBMS_OUTPUT to show the flow of code...

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> get auto_txn_demo.sql
  1  begin
  2      dbms_output.put_line('about to raise exception');
  3      raise value_error;
  4      dbms_output.put_line('about to execute anonymous block');
  5      << anon_block >>
  6      declare
  7          procedure auto_txn is
  8              pragma autonomous_transaction;
  9          begin
 10              dbms_output.put_line('executing autonomous transaction');
 11              commit;
 12          end auto_txn;
 13      begin
 14          dbms_output.put_line('about to call private proc');
 15          auto_txn;
 16      end;
 17  exception
 18      when value_error then
 19          dbms_output.put_line('handling exception');
 20* end;
 21  
 22  /
about to raise exception
handling exception

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```